# Customised WPF DataGrid with dropdown menus in header

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to create a DataGrid which has drop-down menus in the headers and I'm not sure how to go about doing so.

The DataGrid itself is populated from a CSV file which can have many different formats so I can't pre-define the columns in XAML, instead set them up like:

```
 //add headers as columns on the data grid
 var headerRow = _inputFile.GetHeaderRow();
 foreach (var hr in headerRow)
 {
      var textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
      textColumn.Header = hr;
      SourceGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
 }
```

My goal is to also have drop-down menus in the header column (or first row if suitably styled) as the idea is that I'm mapping the input CSV file to a set of pre-defined outputs, so I'd like the user to select per input file header what to map it to via the drop-down menu.

Is it better to attempt to define a data grid template in xaml?  Or perhaps arrange my input data into a class structure which will more easily databind to the grid in the way I want?  Or something else entirely?

I'm fairly new to WPF and having trouble finding where to go from here so even pointers in the right direction would very helpful!

---

Edit:

```
var comboColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
comboColumn.Header = new ComboBox();
SourceGrid.Columns.Add(comboColumn);
```

So I understand I can setup the headers to be text or combo boxes in code, but is there a way to put both a text and combobox in the same column header?
Also, is my approach to solve this problem a good one or should I be looking at a different kind of control?  Or perhaps using databinding instead of setting the values in code?

Comment: Did you get this figured out? Im trying to implement the same thing, currently struggling with binding the combobox selections

Comment: @RyanS Afraid not no. If you come up with a solution please post it here so others can see it :)

Comment: I got the comboboxes in the header but couldnt find an elegant way to bind a dynamic amount of them. I ended up finding an alternative method to accomplish what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will help you to display the Combobox header in wpf.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}">
     <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
      <ComboBox />
     </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: I have to set the headers in code because of the custom format of the CSV files I use for defining those headers.  How can I achieve what your XAML does but in code?

Comment: @peacemaker Here's how you do it in code: myDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn {Header = new ComboBox(), Binding = myBinding});

Comment: Use Eirik suggested solution. It will help you to sort it out.